# How to add login to IOS MasterDetail Universal Project?

Tags: xcode, xamarin.ios, uistoryboard, ios-universal-app, xamarin

I'm new to IOS development.  I'm wanting to add to a new storyboard project that is a universal masterdetail a simple login control that is required before the user can go any further.  that is, I always want them logged in.  I'm using monotouch, but I don't think this question is monotouch specific.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally for login screens, I do the following:

- In `ViewDidAppear` of your root view controller, check if your user needs to login
- Use `PresentModalViewController` to display your login screen modally

This should work for any type of controller you are using as the root controller.

There are certainly other approaches, but this one has always worked for me.

Comment: Hi Jonathan,  I'm sure this should be simple, but could paste in a few lines of code to get me started.  I'm struggling trying to get this working.  (monotouch I'm hoping)

Comment: Can you post the code that isn't working?  This should be straightforward: override `ViewDidAppear`, call `PresentModalViewController`.

Comment: I'm sure Jonathan has the right answer but I could not figure out how to do it. I went down the path of building it with the StoryBoard's and XCode. Not sure how good this is, but I did two blog posts on it including a video.  Open to comments, please post them to my blog or here.  http://peterkellner.net/2012/08/13/building-a-login-screen-with-xamarins-monotouch-and-xcode-storyboard/